# Execute a specific parametrized class method

Tags: java, generics, methods

I have this (simplified) java interface

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    public String run( T arg );
}
```

and some classes that implement that interface, i.e.

```
public final class SomeImplementation1 implements MyInterface<String> {
   @Override
   public String run( String arg) {
       // do something with arg and return a string
   }
}
```

and

```
public final class SomeImplementation2 implements MyInterface<CustomClass> {
   @Override
   public String run( CustomClass arg) {
       // do something with arg and return a string
   }
}
```

Now, I have a global resource manager for all of those implementations, which instantiates all of them in a List for latter usage. What I would like to achieve is something like this, which obviously gives me an error

```
public final class MyInterfaceManager {
    private List<MyInterface<?>> elements = new List<MyInterface<?>>();

    public MyInterfaceManager() {
        elements.put( new SomeImplementation1() );
        elements.put( new SomeImplementation2() );
        // more implementations added
    }

    // this is what I would like to achieve
    public <T> void run( T arg ) {
        for( MyInterface<?> element: elements ) {
            String res = element.run( arg );    // ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

because "arg cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? by method invocation conversion".
A possible solution could be to perform an `instanceof` test inside the loop, and cast the element to its real type, along with the argument as well, like that

```
    public <T> void run( T arg ) {
        for( MyInterface<T> element: elements ) {
            if (element instanceof SomeImplementation2) {
                String res = ((SomeImplementation2)element).run( (CustomClass)arg  );
            } else if // other tests here ...
        }
    }
```

But i don't like it, it's not elegant at all, and it forces me to do lots of `instanceof` and casts.
So, I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You add a `getClass` type method into the `interface` and then simply check `assignableFrom` for each instance in the `List` to see if the passed in parameter can be safely cast to the required parameter and then you `Class.cast` to cast it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks for the suggestion, I will try it tomorrow because it's kinda late over here :)

Comment: @BoristheSpider You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You need to add another method to the `interface` that returns the `Class` instance that relates to the type parameter `<T>`, this will allow you to do runtime checks on that `Class`.

I would accomplish this thus:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    String run( T arg );
    Class<T> type();
}
```

So the `interface` returns its type. N.B. all `interface` members are `public` by default - no need for the extra `public`.

```
public final class SomeImplementation1 implements MyInterface<String> {
   @Override
   public String run(final String arg) {
       return arg;
   }

   @Override
   public Class<String> type() {
       return String.class;
   } 
}

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public static  <T> String run(final T arg) {
    for (final MyInterface<?> element : elements) {
        if (element.type().isAssignableFrom(arg.getClass())) {
            return ((MyInterface<T>) element).run(arg);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No element found.");
}
```

The logic is that for each `MyInterface` you check whether the argument provided is safely castable to that `MyInterface`'s `type()`. If it is then you can cast the whole `MyInterface` to the `arg`'s type. This is unchecked as the compiler cannot verify this as compile time, but as you are manually doing a check this warning can be ignored.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    elements = new LinkedList<>();
    elements.add(new SomeImplementation1());

    System.out.println(run("test"));
    System.out.println(run(1));
}
```

Output:

```
test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No element found.
    at com.XXX.App.run(App.java:33)
    at com.XXX.App.main(App.java:55)
```

As expected.